# Open Gnome Terminal window and execute 2 commands

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a script which runs in the background (without terminal windows or TTY) and occasionally does something.

I now want it to do another thing when it does something and it is to open a Gnome Terminal window and execute 2 commands. Actually, I only need to execute 1 command but I want to make the terminal window stay open so I can see the output of the command. The command prints both on stdout and stderr and its output changes over time, so just writing it to a file and sending some kind of notification wouldn't do the job very well.

I can get Gnome Terminal to open a window and execute 1 command:

```
gnome-terminal -e "sleep 10"
```

I chose `sleep` as the long-running command for simplicity. However, when adding another command, no terminal window opens:

```
gnome-terminal -e "echo test; sleep 10"
```

What's the solution to this?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application/1026563#1026563 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` treats everything in quotes as one command, so in order to run many of them consecutively you need to start interpreter (usually a shell), and do stuff inside it, for instance:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "echo test; sleep 10"'
```

BTW, you may want the window to stay open even after commands finish their job, in such case just start new shell, or replace a current with the new one:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "echo test; sleep 10; exec bash"'
```

Comment: # Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.# 
    # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.#

That error happens now.  But if you replace -e with --, the new terminal that comes up gives an error.  How to correctly use --?

Comment: @eric.frederich based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48628070/9357589) to a question at stackoverflow, I believe the syntax should be `gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo test; sleep 10'`

Answer (score 21):

As of January 2020, the `-e` option in `gnome-terminal` still works, but throws the warning

> # Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version
>   of gnome-terminal.
>
> # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to
>   execute after it.

You can run the two commands without warning with

```sh
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo test; sleep 10'
```

And, as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373188/294686), if you want the window to stay open afterwards, you can do

```sh
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo test; sleep 10; exec bash'
```

*[answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48628070/9357589)

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck placing my commands into an external script, and then running them from the gnome-terminal based 2nd script

script 1: commands.sh

```
#bin/bash
precommand
app
postcommand
```

then a script to execute those within gnome-terminal
runscript.sh:

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar -- /bin/sh commands.sh
```