# unable to print a positional parameter in a script

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm using [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373186/open-gnome-terminal-window-and-execute-2-commands/564491#564491) to open a Gnome terminal window and run command(s) — in this case, to send me simple notification messages (will be scheduled via `at`):

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo "remember: $1"; exec bash'
```

The shell only prints the `remember:` string and not my specified value, for instance when running `remind.sh "pick up the package"` or `remind.sh "buy groceries X and Y"`.

When I strip the script down to its core everything works as expected (of course won't have any use in automation via cron or systemd as nothing is displayed on the foreground):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "remember: $1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Analysis

The code you (or rather `gnome-terminal` in your case) provides to `/bin/sh -c` will see positional parameters provided after the code. E.g. this

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo "remember: $1"; exec bash' zeroth first second …
```

will print `remember: first`.

Providing nothing after the code causes `$1` (or `$2`, `$3` etc.) expand to an empty string when the code is finally interpreted (`$0` is somewhat different but this doesn't matter here). This is the reason you got `remember:`. `/bin/sh` run by `gnome-terminal` simply knows nothing about the positional parameters of the main script, unless you pass them explicitly.

---

#### Solution

To populate positional parameters of the inner code with positional parameters of the script, use `"$@"` instead of `first second …`:

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo "remember: $1"; exec bash' sh "$@"
```

You can pass whatever you want. Here we pass all the parameters (`"$@"` expands to all positional parameters), but in general you can use `"$1"` (if you want the inner code to know the first parameter *only*) or `"$2"` (if you want the inner code to see the *second* positional parameter of the main script as *its own* `$1`).

---

#### Notes

- `sh` as the zeroth argument is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- If in your original script (i.e. without my fix) the shell code you intend to provide to `sh -c` was double-quoted, then the shell interpreted the script would expand `$1` and embed the result in the inner code. Don't do this though.

  ```
  # flawed  
  gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c "echo 'remember: $1'; exec bash"
  ```

  In many cases this would work as you expect; but not in general. In general it is as flawed as [embedding `{}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). Single quoted-code and arguments after it are the right way.
- Single-quoting the code ensures it will get to `/bin/sh -c` as-is ([the inner double-quotes don't matter](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690)). Then `sh` will see the code as

  ```
  echo "remember: $1"; exec bash
  ```

  and [it's very good you double-quoted `$1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) here.

Comment: and if they want to concatenate the args of the script to one arg for the inner `sh -c` command, they'd use `$*`. E.g. `gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo "remember: $1"; exec bash' sh "$*"` would allow running the script as `remind.sh pick up the package` without the quotes (as long as they don't use shell special characters in the message that would need quoting)